# Disable Duplicate checkbox in table is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have table contains checkbox for every rows. `Value` of this checkbox can be duplicate in another rows. If I check any one row and same `value` is exist in another rows then I want to disable another rows contains the same value except current row.

HTML and JQuery script is as below -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        //debugger;
        value = $(this).attr('value');
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + value + ']:not(#' + id + ')')
            .attr('disabled', checked);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table class="ptlfData">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <th>Select Transaction ID</th>
             <th style="display:none;">Sr.No</th>
             <th>Transaction ID / UTR No.</th>
             <th>Transaction Time (HH:MM:SS:MS)</th>
             <th>Transaction Type</th>
             <th>Transaction Amount</th>
             <th style="display:none;">Dispensed Amount</th>
             <th>Terminal ID</th>
             <th>Bank Name</th>
             <th>Request Category</th>
             <th>Category Code</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="pointer">
             <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" value="50000014"  id="50000014_1" name="case[]"></td>
             <td style="display:none;"></td>
             <td class="accountNumber">JU5532719846</td>
             <td>1313100</td>
             <td>DEBIT</td>
             <td>20</td>
             <td style="display:none;">0</td>
             <td>50000014</td>
             <td>BDPG</td>
             <td>BDPG</td>
             <td>794</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="pointer">
             <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" value="50000231" id="50000231_2" name="case[]"></td>
             <td style="display:none;"></td>
             <td class="accountNumber">JU5532670793</td>
             <td>23592200</td>
             <td>DEBIT</td>
             <td>1282</td>
             <td style="display:none;">0</td>
             <td>50000231</td>
             <td>BDPG</td>
             <td>BDPG</td>
             <td>794</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="pointer">
             <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" value="50000014" id="7223900_3" name="case[]"></td>
             <td style="display:none;"></td>
             <td class="accountNumber">JU5532797963</td>
             <td>7223900</td>
             <td>DEBIT</td>
             <td>400</td>
             <td style="display:none;">0</td>
             <td>50000392</td>
             <td>BDPG</td>
             <td>BDPG</td>
             <td>794</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Whenever I am checking the same in debugging mode it is throwing error `checked` is not defined.

I have refer solution mentioned in below URL

[JQuery - disable duplicate checkboxes when checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657630/jquery-disable-duplicate-checkboxes-when-checked)

Comment: You can use a radio input for these values.

Comment: Try checked = $(this).is(‘:checked’);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
checked = $(this).prop('checked');
```

instead

```
checked = $(this).attr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below acts as you have requested, disabling checkboxes with the same `.val()`. It also adds the class `.disabled` to the associated rows so that you can show this more clearly to the user.

---

## Explaination of Code

**Is the checkbox checked?**

You can use an `if` statement as below, where `.is(':checked')` returns the boolean `true` if the element in question has been checked.

```
if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
   ...
}
```

**Disabling the other checkboxes**

You can gather the `.val()` of the checked checkbox as follows:

```
tempVal = $(this).val();
```

Disabling the other checkboxes is a multiple step process, the entire command is as follows:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value=" + val + "]").not(this).attr("disabled", true).closest("tr").addClass("disabled");
```

Where each of the components is explained below:

- `$("input[type=checkbox][value=" + val + "]")` selects all checkboxes with the specified value
- `.not(this)` excludes the current element (as we don't want to disable the clicked checkbox)
- `.attr("disabled", true)` disables the checkboxes
- `.closest("tr")` moves up the DOM tree to the closest table row for each checkbox that has been disabled
- `.addClass("disabled");` adds a class to that table row so that we can apply some tyling for the user

---

## Demo

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function() {

  // Get value from checkbox
  val = $(this).val();
  
  // Check if the checkbox has been checked
  if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
  
    // Disable checkboxes with that value
    // Also adds class to row to show it is disabled
    // Skip $(this) checkbox
    $("input[type=checkbox][value=" + val + "]").not(this).attr("disabled", true).closest("tr").addClass("disabled");
    
    
    
  } else {

    // Enable checkboxes is the checkbox is being unchecked
    $("input[type=checkbox][value=" + val + "]").attr("disabled", false).closest("tr").removeClass("disabled");
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
tr.disabled * {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ptlfData">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Select Transaction ID</th>
      <th style="display:none;">Sr.No</th>
      <th>Transaction ID / UTR No.</th>
      <th>Transaction Time (HH:MM:SS:MS)</th>
      <th>Transaction Type</th>
      <th>Transaction Amount</th>
      <th style="display:none;">Dispensed Amount</th>
      <th>Terminal ID</th>
      <th>Bank Name</th>
      <th>Request Category</th>
      <th>Category Code</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pointer">
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" value="50000014" id="50000014_1" name="case[]">50000014</td>
      <td style="display:none;"></td>
      <td class="accountNumber">JU5532719846</td>
      <td>1313100</td>
      <td>DEBIT</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td style="display:none;">0</td>
      <td>50000014</td>
      <td>BDPG</td>
      <td>BDPG</td>
      <td>794</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pointer">
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" value="50000231" id="50000231_2" name="case[]">50000231</td>
      <td style="display:none;"></td>
      <td class="accountNumber">JU5532670793</td>
      <td>23592200</td>
      <td>DEBIT</td>
      <td>1282</td>
      <td style="display:none;">0</td>
      <td>50000231</td>
      <td>BDPG</td>
      <td>BDPG</td>
      <td>794</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pointer">
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" value="50000014" id="7223900_3" name="case[]">50000014</td>
      <td style="display:none;"></td>
      <td class="accountNumber">JU5532797963</td>
      <td>7223900</td>
      <td>DEBIT</td>
      <td>400</td>
      <td style="display:none;">0</td>
      <td>50000392</td>
      <td>BDPG</td>
      <td>BDPG</td>
      <td>794</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `checked = $(this).attr('checked');` to `checked = $(this).is( ':checked' );`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for that. Iterates over checkboxes with the same value, but deactivates those without the same id.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        value = $(this).attr('value');
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        // disables any checkbox with the same value, but without the same id 
        $(`input[value="${value}"]`).each(function(i,v){ 
            if(v.id !== id){
                v.checked = false;
            }
         });
    });
});
```